# Transform XML into multiple CSV using XSLT

Tags: c#, .net, xml, csv, xslt

For example, I have XML file with a following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainItem>
    <Field1>1</Field1>
    <Field2>2</Field2>  
    <SubItem>
        <SubField1>1</SubField1>
        <SubField2>2</SubField2>
    </SubItem>
    <SubItem>
        <SubField1>3</SubField1>
        <SubField2>4</SubField2>
    </SubItem>
</MainItem>
```

I know for sure that there is always only one `MainItem` in XML file. At the same time, one `MainItem` may have multiple `SubItem` elements. 
I want to be able to transform this XML into CSV using XSLT. Below is my current XSLT script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">    
<xsl:text>Field1,Field2</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
<xsl:for-each select="MainItem">
    <xsl:value-of select="Field1"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Field2"/>     
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

This XSLT transforms XML into following CSV:

```
Field1,Field2
1,2
```

The question is how can I use XSLT to transform the above-mentioned XML into 2 CSV files - the first one for `MainItem` element, the second one for `SubItem`?

I'm using .NET `XslCompiledTransform` class to perform transformation.

Comment: If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova you can use `xsl:result-document` to create several result documents with one transformation. If you use an XSLT 1.0 processor you need to check whether it supports an extension element to create multiple result documents.

Comment: I am not aware of support of XslCompiledTransform to create several result documents with one transformation, other than trying to use extension object or script to delegate the creation to .NET code. And in that case it is probably easier to write two separate XSLT stylesheets and then use .NET code outside of XSLT to run both stylesheets separately to create your two CSV files. With .NET however you have the option to move to XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 by switching to Saxon 9 (HE edition is open source and available on NuGet) or XmlPrime or Altova.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm going to use XSLT 2.0 with Saxon HE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something doable using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) library (an open source ETL framework)

```
using (var reader = new ChoXmlReader("test.xml").WithXPath("MainItem")
    .WithField('Field1')
    .WithField('Field2')
)
{
    using (var writer = new ChoCSVWriter("test.csv"))
        writer.Write(reader);
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.